# IBM 4690 SI AEF extension for ACE

Tags: javapos

I am looking to write a scanner event and listener to perform a specific task .the SI programming docs mainly refers to that of RMI CSS sessions but am looking to run this only on local terminal.Am a newbie when it comes to java and SI AEF programming. Any pointers would be of great help.

Comment: Still need an answer?  I would have to dig through some documentation, but I've done that before with SI-Gui.  Are you running SI-Gui on top of Ace?

Comment: Yes I would like to hear any information or pointersyou are correct,  It's on top of ACE.